# How can I save multi-line code snippets in MongoDB, retrieve and display them in HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on React web app that (amongst other things) renders out certain snippets of code that are stored in a database.

For instance, say I want to store the following code block, including indentation and newlines, in a MongoDB database and display it on the page:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <p class='child'>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

How should I format this string of code to store it in MongoDB, and what would I need to do to render it with the same formatting on the page? I tried storing the string with `\n` in place of the new-lines in my MongoDB database, but that renders the text "\n" in the browser after I retrieve and display it, even if that text is wrapped in `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can save code as a string in a MongoDB database, with \n as newlines. The trick is to use a React component that will then correctly parse the string and format it according to the rules of the language, e.g. JavaScript.

I personally use a markdown parser called Markdown-It that can use a highlighting library such as highlight.js or prism and format the code for display within pre / code tags.

Here is a condensed example of how I render a string returned from a MongoDB database and display it as code in a React component:

// CodeDisplay.js

```
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it";
import hljs from "highlight.js/lib/core";
import javascript from "highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript";
hljs.registerLanguage("javascript", javascript);

export default function CodeDisplay({
  code,
  technology = "javascript"
}) {
  return (
    <div
      className="code_display"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: markdownParser.render(`\`\`\` ${technology}\n${code}\n\`\`\``)
      }}
    />
  );
}

const markdownParser = new MarkdownIt({
  breaks: true,
  highlight: function (str: string, lang = "javascript") {
    if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
      try {
        return `<pre class="hljs"><code>${
          hljs.highlight(lang, str, true).value
        }</code></pre>`;
      } catch (error) {}
    }
    return `<pre class="hljs"><code>${markdownParser.utils.escapeHtml(
      str
    )}</code></pre>`;
  }
});
```

The above component will take in my code string and the language that I wish to syntax highlight, and render it out.

Here is an example of what is stored as a string in my MongoDB database:

```
"const Animal = (name, type) => {\n  this.name = name\n  this.type = type\n  this.age = 0\n}\n\nAnimal.prototype.birthday = function () {\n  this.age++\n}\n\nconst leo = new Animal('Leo', 'Lion')"
```

And here is how the CodeDisplay component will render it:

[image]

So, it's actually reasonably simple, at least when it comes to storing the code - just store it as a basic string with line breaks, and then parse it / highlight it and display it in a component in React.

I guess you asked this question a while ago, hope you got it sorted, and hope it helps anyone else running into this issue!